# How to determine if 2D line is in a polygon?

Tags: algorithm, go, data-structures

Bear with me.

I have a polygon data, where I am probably not allowed to share the whole exact input but take this:

`-5.0000,-1.0000;-5.0000,-4.0000;5.0000,-4.0000;5.0000,0.0000;2.0000,-3.0000;1.0000,-1.0000`

This is a polygon, where vertexes are split by `;` and vertex coordinates are split by `,`. I have a lot of lines of polygon data, where everything forms a closed shape.

Now, I also have line of coordinates where:

`-5.5380,-1.7205;-6.3484,-3.1333`

This is a query point, vertexes are split by `;` and vertex coordinates are split by `,`. I want to determine if this line is inside the polygons that is provided.

I currently have a ray casting algorithm but my current implementation only checks if one single point is in the shape boundaries that is set by polygons:

```
type Point struct {
    X float64
    Y float64
}
func intersect(vertexes []Point, testx float64, testy float64) bool {
    // poor implementation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon#Ray_casting_algorithm
    var c = false
    // vertexes is the list of the vertexes of the polygon
    //
    // testx is the x coordinate of the query point
    //
    // testy is the y coordinate of the query point
    //
    // now, for every vertex, check if the query point is inside the polygon.
    // by casting a ray from the query point to the semi-infinite right, and checking if it intersects with the polygon.
    //
    // iterate through the vertexes of the polygon
    polygonVertexCount := len(vertexes)
    for index := range vertexes {
        currentVertex := vertexes[index]
        nextVertex := vertexes[(index+1)%polygonVertexCount]
        // if the vertex is above the query point, and the next vertex is below the query point, or vice versa, then check if the query point is inside the polygon.
        //
        // if the query point is inside the polygon, then the ray will intersect with the polygon.
        //
        // conditions:
        //
        // -> if current polygon vertex's y is greater than the query point's y, and the vertex that is next to the current polygon vertex's y is less than the query point's y, or vice versa, then check if the query point is inside the polygon.
        //
        // -> if the test point's x is less than the x coordinate of the line that is formed by the current polygon vertex and the next polygon vertex, then the ray will intersect with the polygon.
        //
        // both conditions must be true for the ray to intersect with the polygon.
        //
        // line equation: y = mx + b, where
        //
        // -> b is the y-intercept, which is the x coordinate of the current polygon vertex.
        // -> m is the slope, which is the difference between the y coordinates of the current polygon vertex and the next polygon vertex,
        //    divided by the difference between the x coordinates of the current polygon vertex and the next polygon vertex.
        // -> x is the x coordinate of the next query point that is subtracted by the x coordinate of the current polygon vertex.
        //
        // https://www.ncl.ac.uk/webtemplate/ask-assets/external/maths-resources/core-mathematics/geometry/equation-of-a-straight-line.html#:~:text=The%20equation%20of%20a%20straight,known%20as%20the%20y%20%2Dintercept.
        if ((currentVertex.Y > testy) != (nextVertex.Y > testy)) &&
            (testx < (nextVertex.X-currentVertex.X)*(testy-currentVertex.Y)/(nextVertex.Y-currentVertex.Y)+currentVertex.X) {
            c = !c
        }
    }
    return c
}
```

How can I tweak this so that I can test if lines are in polygon,instead of just one single point?

[Red lines will return false, blue lines will return true.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt9vj.png)

Comment: Added a very ugly drawing for what I want

Comment: If any point on the line segment is inside the polygon and the line segment does not intersect a polygon edge, then all points on the line segment are inside the polygon.

Comment: @CeriseLimón can you please write this as answer so I can accept it? I could derive some pseudocode from it, so it may be useful for doods in future